# How to make email alerts customizable?

Tags: nagios

I'm running Nagios 3. It is generating the alerts that are based on my conditions that I had mentioned.

What I want now is to customize my email alerts with a detailed messages. I need to send alerts for my tomcat logs along with the stack trace.

In my `commands.cfg` file, I have `command_line` like this :

```
 command_line /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /usr/local/bin/sendEmail -v -f x.x.x.x. -t  x.x.x.x -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu x.x.x..x -xp x.x.x.x. -l /var/log/sendEmail -u "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" -m "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$"
```

How do I customize it? Where are the variables like `$SERVICEOUTPUT$` coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These variables like `$SERVICEOUTPUT$` are coming from the service check that nagios is doing. Other variables like `$HOSTADDRESS$` are coming from the host/service definition.

Actually, these are called macros in nagios terms. You can have a look at [this page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html) to find the list of macros.

Comment: So typically if I want to return the stack trace of Tomcat in case of an error, how could I do that?

Comment: @Ant's: One possible way is to print the stack trace in the service check script. In this case, you can get the values of `$SERVICEOUTPUT$` and `$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$` macros and include these in your email.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I have written the script for it, I will return the stack trace when Nagios find its critical. BTW, where does the macros reside in Ubuntu? Can I be able to add/modify the parameters macros?

Comment: @Ant's: These macros are nagios-related only and have nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: No, what I tried is to ask the location of macros file/directory under Nagios installation. Sorry if my English is bad